# Entity Framework connection string in Service Fabric configurations

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, connection-string, azure-service-fabric, configuration-files

I'm trying to run existing WCF service as a stateful reliable service. The WCF service uses EF4's object context API that requires connection string in the form of

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=My-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User=sa;Password=password;Integrated Security=false&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Previously the service could easily find this connection string from config file by referencing to its name. Now in Service Fabric I have to specify any custom configuration in Settings.xml file under Config folder of my package that only seems to support key values like this:

```
<Section Name="ConnectionStrings">
    <Parameter Name="Entities" Value="metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=My-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User=sa;Password=password;Integrated Security=false&quot;"/>
</Section>
```

How do I specify the provider name here?

Comment: You don't. You just read the connecting string and pass it to the object context constructor.

Comment: I get the Argument Exception `Keyword not supported: 'data source'`I searched for it and I have to specify provider name to resolve it.

Comment: You can set tet manually, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902496/how-to-set-connection-string-with-entity-framework

Comment: It worked :) So there is no direct way to specify it in the configuration file? Does SF ignore the .config files of the executable project and use only Settings.xml? As I have other things in .config files as well like logging configurations etc.